# Using changestamp in GoogleDocs (null changestamp)

Tags: gdata, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to find the max changestamp so I can start using it.  I tried the following:

```
URL url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/changes?v=3"
ChangelogFeed foo = service.getFeed(url, ChangelogFeed.class);
LargestChangestamp stamp = foo.getLargestChangestamp();
```

stamp is always null.

Is this the way to get the largest changestamp, or do I need to set it first in order to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The largest changestamp is also available in the user metadata feed.  See the "docs:largestChangestamp" element within the response protocol tab [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_general_information_about_a_users_account),

I'm not sure the java api exposes the largestChangestamp property directly yet - last time I checked it was hidden in the xmlBlob property, and I had to do an xml parse to grab it out.

Comment: getLargestChangestamp returns null as well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the API.  I got the changestamps by getting the ChangelogEntrys from the ChangelogFeed:

```
List<ChangelogEntry> entries = foo.getEntries();
    for (ChangelogEntry entry: entries) {
    String blob = entry.getXmlBlob().getBlob();
    System.out.println("Blob: " + blob);
}
```

The changestamp for an entry is contained in its blob.